# spring config server- for local git repository

Tags: java, spring, git, microservices, spring-boot-2

I'm trying to setting up spring cloud config server

-Created git repository folder on my local 
F:\git-local-repository\repository

-linked it using class path link source
-Added property file for my service

-After committing my changes on location F:\git-local-repository\repository

-hitting url : http://localhost:8888/limits/default

result in error :
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved

Following is my main class of spring boot application

```
@EnableConfigServer


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);


}

}

application.properties

spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:////F:/git-local- 
repository/repository
```

expected result: will be showing application property details and other url's

Comment: Please mention your application and bootstrap. Yml file

Comment: updated application.properties file not using bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a local directory for configuration.

Instead of

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:////F:/git-local-repository/repository
```

Use

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:////F:/git-local-repository/repository
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with extra forward slash.
Please change to this :

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///F:/git-local- 
repository/repository
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because git change the default name of the branch, now it is main, while spring is searching for master.

Adding 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main' fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are issuing NoSuchLabelException you can try to add spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=branch-name property to lead your spring cloud config server directly to this branch.

Answer (score -1):

Adding bootstrap.yml file with following configuration worked for me.

```
spring:
   application:
        name: spring-cloud-config-server
profiles:
active: composite
cloud:
 config:
  server:
    composite:
      - type: native
        search-locations: file:////F:/git-local-repository/repository
          bootstrap: true
server:
  port: 8888
endpoints:
  restart:
     enabled: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Did so many things to resolve this however it was adding

spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main to application.properties worked