# Spring Cloud Configuration Server not working with local properties file - getting need to use a composite configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am configuring the new `spring config server` and getting the below error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

I have tried the below links but no luck
[Spring Cloud Config Server configuration with local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557032/spring-cloud-config-server-configuration-with-local-repository)
[spring config server- for local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257587/spring-config-server-for-local-git-repository)
https://medium.com/@danismaz.furkan/spring-cloud-config-with-file-system-backend-c18ae16b7ad5

**bootstrap.properties**

```
server.port = 8888
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///C:/configprop/
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fis</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-sever</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-sever</name>
    <description>configuration server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: You need to activate the native profile

Comment: @spencergibb Tried no luck

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried `spring.profiles.active=native`

Comment: I think at this point I'd need to see a sample project

Comment: The answer provided below works. I renamed the file name to `application.properties`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should rename your `bootstrap.properties` file to `application.properties` (see [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html)).

And use native profile like @spencergibb recommended in comments section (see [File system backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend)), either by adding the following line to `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=native
```

or passing it externally see  ([Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)), e.g.

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=native
```

Comment: That worked for me, I added it in my application.yml and it worked. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me. Fixed the error "Invalid config server configuration".  I renamed bootstrap.yml in application.yml in my ConfigServer project and it worked. I'm using spring boot 3.0.2 and spring cloud 2022.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency in your pom in order not to let your bootstrap be ignored.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```